# Why does this element translate to 0,0,0 in my SVG/CSS/JS animation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I'm trying to animate an SVG I created in Inkscape using CSS/JS, and it seems like it should be fairly simple: I'm just adding the `.rotating` class to `#gear-small` on hover:

```
.logo {
  overflow: visible;
  transform: scale(0.5);
}

.rotating {
  animation-name: rotate; 
  animation-duration: 3s; 
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}

@keyframes rotate {
  from {transform: rotate(0deg);}
  to {transform: rotate(360deg);}
}
```

The problem is that, although the element rotates, it also seems to move to 0,0,0. I'm not sure what's going on here. I suspect it might have to do with the inline transform properties, but I'm pretty dumb on this one, so any help would be appreciated.

Looking at the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mj2ozjvd/1/) I made should make everything clear.

I've tried overriding transform properties in my stylesheet, but it still seems to translate it to 0,0,0 no matter what I do.

Edit: To be clear, the gear is supposed to stay in place and rotate like a wheel.

Edit: Here's the complete html, css and js (as per requested, sorry about that):

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'/>
    <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='test.css'/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <svg
      class='logo'
      width="64.32mm" height="120.5mm" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 64.32 120.5" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <g fill="#b3b3b3" stroke="#000" stroke-width=".26458">
        <g id="gear-small" transform="translate(40.785 47.68)">
          <path d="m8.3326-1.2236 1.0635-0.15617 0.6238 0.06064 1.7592 0.79639v1.0455l-1.7592 0.79639-0.6238 0.06064-1.0635-0.15617-0.50455 1.883 0.9991 0.3965 0.5099 0.36441 1.1254 1.5693-0.52274 0.90542-1.9218-0.18993-0.57054-0.25938-0.84293-0.667-1.3785 1.3785 0.667 0.84293 0.25938 0.57054 0.18993 1.9218-0.90542 0.52274-1.5693-1.1254-0.36441-0.5099-0.3965-0.9991-1.883 0.50455 0.15617 1.0635-0.06064 0.6238-0.79639 1.7592h-1.0455l-0.79639-1.7592-0.06064-0.6238 0.15617-1.0635-1.883-0.50455-0.3965 0.9991-0.36441 0.5099-1.5693 1.1254-0.90542-0.52274 0.18993-1.9218 0.25938-0.57054 0.667-0.84293-1.3785-1.3785-0.84293 0.667-0.57054 0.25938-1.9218 0.18993-0.52274-0.90542 1.1254-1.5693 0.5099-0.36441 0.9991-0.3965-0.50455-1.883-1.0635 0.15617-0.6238-0.06064-1.7592-0.79639v-1.0455l1.7592-0.79639 0.6238-0.06064 1.0635 0.15617 0.50455-1.883-0.9991-0.3965-0.5099-0.36441-1.1254-1.5693 0.52274-0.90542 1.9218 0.18993 0.57054 0.25938 0.84293 0.667 1.3785-1.3785-0.667-0.84293-0.25938-0.57054-0.18993-1.9218 0.90542-0.52274 1.5693 1.1254 0.36441 0.5099 0.3965 0.9991 1.883-0.50455-0.15617-1.0635 0.06064-0.6238 0.79639-1.7592h1.0455l0.79639 1.7592 0.06064 0.6238-0.15617 1.0635 1.883 0.50455 0.3965-0.9991 0.36441-0.5099 1.5693-1.1254 0.90542 0.52274-0.18993 1.9218-0.25938 0.57054-0.667 0.84293 1.3785 1.3785 0.84293-0.667 0.57054-0.25938 1.9218-0.18993 0.52274 0.90542-1.1254 1.5693-0.5099 0.36441-0.9991 0.3965z"/>
          <circle r="7.9375"/>
        </g>
        <g id="gear-medium" transform="translate(22.021 22.021)">
          <path d="m18.468-1.4872 0.46392-0.03736 1.237 0.20261 1.7194 0.71941v1.2051l-1.7194 0.71941-1.237 0.20261-0.46392-0.03736-0.24437 1.8562 0.45777 0.08399 1.1424 0.51586 1.4746 1.1399-0.31191 1.164-1.847 0.24989-1.2473-0.12445-0.43844-0.15615-0.71647 1.7297 0.42044 0.1996 0.96995 0.79396 1.1293 1.4827-0.60255 1.0437-1.8487-0.23666-1.1726-0.44302-0.38308-0.26431-1.1398 1.4854 0.35445 0.30162 0.73142 1.0179 0.70707 1.7245-0.85214 0.85214-1.7245-0.70707-1.0179-0.73142-0.30162-0.35445-1.4854 1.1398 0.26431 0.38308 0.44302 1.1726 0.23666 1.8487-1.0437 0.60255-1.4827-1.1293-0.79396-0.96995-0.1996-0.42044-1.7297 0.71647 0.15615 0.43844 0.12445 1.2473-0.24989 1.847-1.164 0.31191-1.1399-1.4746-0.51586-1.1424-0.08399-0.45777-1.8562 0.24437 0.03736 0.46392-0.20261 1.237-0.71941 1.7194h-1.2051l-0.71941-1.7194-0.20261-1.237 0.03736-0.46392-1.8562-0.24437-0.08399 0.45777-0.51586 1.1424-1.1399 1.4746-1.164-0.31191-0.24989-1.847 0.12445-1.2473 0.15615-0.43844-1.7297-0.71647-0.1996 0.42044-0.79396 0.96995-1.4827 1.1293-1.0437-0.60255 0.23666-1.8487 0.44302-1.1726 0.26431-0.38308-1.4854-1.1398-0.30162 0.35445-1.0179 0.73142-1.7245 0.70707-0.85214-0.85214 0.70707-1.7245 0.73142-1.0179 0.35445-0.30162-1.1398-1.4854-0.38308 0.26431-1.1726 0.44302-1.8487 0.23666-0.60255-1.0437 1.1293-1.4827 0.96995-0.79396 0.42044-0.1996-0.71647-1.7297-0.43844 0.15615-1.2473 0.12445-1.847-0.24989-0.31191-1.164 1.4746-1.1399 1.1424-0.51586 0.45777-0.08399-0.24437-1.8562-0.46392 0.03736-1.237-0.20261-1.7194-0.71941v-1.2051l1.7194-0.71941 1.237-0.20261 0.46392 0.03736 0.24437-1.8562-0.45777-0.08399-1.1424-0.51586-1.4746-1.1399 0.31191-1.164 1.847-0.24989 1.2473 0.12445 0.43844 0.15615 0.71647-1.7297-0.42044-0.1996-0.96995-0.79396-1.1293-1.4827 0.60255-1.0437 1.8487 0.23666 1.1726 0.44302 0.38308 0.26431 1.1398-1.4854-0.35445-0.30162-0.73142-1.0179-0.70707-1.7245 0.85214-0.85214 1.7245 0.70707 1.0179 0.73142 0.30162 0.35445 1.4854-1.1398-0.26431-0.38308-0.44302-1.1726-0.23666-1.8487 1.0437-0.60255 1.4827 1.1293 0.79396 0.96995 0.1996 0.42044 1.7297-0.71647-0.15615-0.43844-0.12445-1.2473 0.24989-1.847 1.164-0.31191 1.1399 1.4746 0.51586 1.1424 0.08399 0.45777 1.8562-0.24437-0.03736-0.46392 0.20261-1.237 0.71941-1.7194h1.2051l0.71941 1.7194 0.20261 1.237-0.03736 0.46392 1.8562 0.24437 0.08399-0.45777 0.51586-1.1424 1.1399-1.4746 1.164 0.31191 0.24989 1.847-0.12445 1.2473-0.15615 0.43844 1.7297 0.71647 0.1996-0.42044 0.79396-0.96995 1.4827-1.1293 1.0437 0.60255-0.23666 1.8487-0.44302 1.1726-0.26431 0.38308 1.4854 1.1398 0.30162-0.35445 1.0179-0.73142 1.7245-0.70707 0.85214 0.85214-0.70707 1.7245-0.73142 1.0179-0.35445 0.30162 1.1398 1.4854 0.38308-0.26431 1.1726-0.44302 1.8487-0.23666 0.60255 1.0437-1.1293 1.4827-0.96995 0.79396-0.42044 0.1996 0.71647 1.7297 0.43844-0.15615 1.2473-0.12445 1.847 0.24989 0.31191 1.164-1.4746 1.1399-1.1424 0.51586-0.45777 0.08399z"/>
          <circle r="7.9375"/>
        </g>
        <g id="gear-large" transform="translate(32.191 88.375)">
          <path d="m28.586-1.6656 1.704 0.34308 1.707 0.68859v1.2678l-1.707 0.68859-1.704 0.34308-0.14507 1.6581 1.6186 0.63377 1.5615 0.97454-0.22016 1.2486-1.8006 0.38172-1.7377 0.04196-0.43078 1.6077 1.4839 0.90519 1.3685 1.2309-0.43361 1.1914-1.8395 0.06325-1.7186-0.26042-0.70341 1.5085 1.3042 1.1491 1.134 1.4498-0.63391 1.098-1.8226-0.25714-1.6473-0.5549-0.95467 1.3634 1.0848 1.3581 0.865 1.6247-0.81494 0.9712-1.7502-0.56973-1.5259-0.8325-1.1769 1.1769 0.8325 1.5259 0.56973 1.7502-0.9712 0.81494-1.6247-0.865-1.3581-1.0848-1.3634 0.95467 0.5549 1.6473 0.25714 1.8226-1.098 0.63391-1.4498-1.134-1.1491-1.3042-1.5085 0.70341 0.26042 1.7186-0.06325 1.8395-1.1914 0.43361-1.2309-1.3685-0.90519-1.4839-1.6077 0.43078-0.04196 1.7377-0.38172 1.8006-1.2486 0.22016-0.97454-1.5615-0.63377-1.6186-1.6581 0.14507-0.34308 1.704-0.68859 1.707h-1.2678l-0.68859-1.707-0.34308-1.704-1.6581-0.14507-0.63377 1.6186-0.97454 1.5615-1.2486-0.22016-0.38172-1.8006-0.04196-1.7377-1.6077-0.43078-0.90519 1.4839-1.2309 1.3685-1.1914-0.43361-0.06325-1.8395 0.26042-1.7186-1.5085-0.70341-1.1491 1.3042-1.4498 1.134-1.098-0.63391 0.25714-1.8226 0.5549-1.6473-1.3634-0.95467-1.3581 1.0848-1.6247 0.865-0.9712-0.81494 0.56973-1.7502 0.8325-1.5259-1.1769-1.1769-1.5259 0.8325-1.7502 0.56973-0.81494-0.9712 0.865-1.6247 1.0848-1.3581-0.95467-1.3634-1.6473 0.5549-1.8226 0.25714-0.63391-1.098 1.134-1.4498 1.3042-1.1491-0.70341-1.5085-1.7186 0.26042-1.8395-0.06325-0.43361-1.1914 1.3685-1.2309 1.4839-0.90519-0.43078-1.6077-1.7377-0.04196-1.8006-0.38172-0.22016-1.2486 1.5615-0.97454 1.6186-0.63377-0.14507-1.6581-1.704-0.34308-1.707-0.68859v-1.2678l1.707-0.68859 1.704-0.34308 0.14507-1.6581-1.6186-0.63377-1.5615-0.97454 0.22016-1.2486 1.8006-0.38172 1.7377-0.04196 0.43078-1.6077-1.4839-0.90519-1.3685-1.2309 0.43361-1.1914 1.8395-0.06325 1.7186 0.26042 0.70341-1.5085-1.3042-1.1491-1.134-1.4498 0.63391-1.098 1.8226 0.25714 1.6473 0.5549 0.95467-1.3634-1.0848-1.3581-0.865-1.6247 0.81494-0.9712 1.7502 0.56973 1.5259 0.8325 1.1769-1.1769-0.8325-1.5259-0.56973-1.7502 0.9712-0.81494 1.6247 0.865 1.3581 1.0848 1.3634-0.95467-0.5549-1.6473-0.25714-1.8226 1.098-0.63391 1.4498 1.134 1.1491 1.3042 1.5085-0.70341-0.26042-1.7186 0.06325-1.8395 1.1914-0.43361 1.2309 1.3685 0.90519 1.4839 1.6077-0.43078 0.04196-1.7377 0.38172-1.8006 1.2486-0.22016 0.97454 1.5615 0.63377 1.6186 1.6581-0.14507 0.34308-1.704 0.68859-1.707h1.2678l0.68859 1.707 0.34308 1.704 1.6581 0.14507 0.63377-1.6186 0.97454-1.5615 1.2486 0.22016 0.38172 1.8006 0.04196 1.7377 1.6077 0.43078 0.90519-1.4839 1.2309-1.3685 1.1914 0.43361 0.06325 1.8395-0.26042 1.7186 1.5085 0.70341 1.1491-1.3042 1.4498-1.134 1.098 0.63391-0.25714 1.8226-0.5549 1.6473 1.3634 0.95467 1.3581-1.0848 1.6247-0.865 0.9712 0.81494-0.56973 1.7502-0.8325 1.5259 1.1769 1.1769 1.5259-0.8325 1.7502-0.56973 0.81494 0.9712-0.865 1.6247-1.0848 1.3581 0.95467 1.3634 1.6473-0.5549 1.8226-0.25714 0.63391 1.098-1.134 1.4498-1.3042 1.1491 0.70341 1.5085 1.7186-0.26042 1.8395 0.06325 0.43361 1.1914-1.3685 1.2309-1.4839 0.90519 0.43078 1.6077 1.7377 0.04196 1.8006 0.38172 0.22016 1.2486-1.5615 0.97454-1.6186 0.63377z"/>
          <circle r="7.9375"/>
        </g>
      </g>
    </svg>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="test.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

test.css:

```
.logo {
  overflow: visible;
  transform: scale(0.5);
}

#gear-small {
  transform: translate(40.785, 47.68) !important;
}


.rotating {
  animation-name: rotate; 
  animation-duration: 3s; 
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}

@keyframes rotate {
  from {transform: rotate(0deg);}
  to {transform: rotate(360deg);}
}
```

test.js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.logo').hover(function() {
    $('#gear-small').addClass('rotating');
  }, function() {
    $('#gear-small').removeClass('rotating');
  });
});
```

Comment: You are required to post your markup and code here, not a fiddle which can change or disappear tomorrow helping no one in the future: [mcve]

Comment: @Rob, I edited my post. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add the initial transformation to your keyframes, so it's being overriden:

```
@keyframes rotate {
  from {transform: translate(40.785px, 47.68px) rotate(0deg);}
  to {transform: translate(40.785px, 47.68px) rotate(360deg);}
}
```

Please see the updated jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mj2ozjvd/2/

You may update `animation-duration` with the correct timings (it's easy to count) for the precize animation.

Comment: You should not answer this question because he did not supply code here. Your own answer, and this whole question, becomes pointless when the link dies in the future. [mcve]

Comment: Thanks for helping. This is the solution. I'm kind of new to svg/css animation and I didn't know you had to do this.

Answer (score 0):

There is an implicit transform origin of 0,0,0

I changed it to be 23,23,23, have a look at the effect of that:

```
.rotating {
  animation-name: rotate; 
  animation-duration: 3s; 
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  transform-origin: 23px 23px 23px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/auext03x/

**UPDATE**
I moved the circle of the small cog (instead of using transform), and put a move at the beginning of the path for the cog.

https://jsfiddle.net/auext03x/

Comment: Thanks for answering. Unfortunately this isn't the effect I'm looking for. Other than rotating (like a wheel), the gear is supposed to remain stationary. Do you know if there's any way to disable the implicit transform or override it so that the gear stays in place? Very much appreciated.

Comment: thanks for helping. Someone solved my problem earlier, though. I appreciate it nevertheless.

Comment: No worries, there is learning in everything, his solution was different (and neater too, but basically the same result)